# How to add html reporting to a cucumber/chimp e2e test

Tags: gulp, cucumber, e2e-testing

I am using the example provided on the chimp website for gulp-chimp

```
gulp.task('chimp-options', () => {
    return chimp({
        features: './features',
        browser: 'phantomjs',
        singleRun: true,
        debug: false,
        output: {
            screenshotsPath: './screenshots',
            jsonOutput: './cucumber.json',
        },
        htmlReport: {
            enable: true,
            jsonFile: './e2e_output/cucumber.json',
            output: './e2e_output/report/cucumber.html',
            reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
            launchReport: true,
        }
    });
});
```

the problem i have and that it's killing me is that when I run gulp chimp-options i get :

```
Unable to parse cucumberjs output into json: './e2e_output/cucumber.json' SyntaxError: ./e2e_output/cucumber.json: Unexpected end of JSON input

What am I doing wrong ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe chimp is just a wrapper on multiple frameworks/libraries out there and I'm pretty sure they just use [cucumber-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter) to generate its HTML reports.

If you still can't get it working automatically via chimp, just generate the options file as usual and `npm install cucumber-html-reporter` and then use it to generate the same report.

Create a separate file called `generate_html_report.js` and paste in the code under Usage. Then add this to your npm script to run after your test suite has finished. I'd avoid putting it in your `afterHooks` as I've had issues in the past where the JSON file hadn't been completely generated before it tries to run the script expecting the JSON file to be there.